# React Three Fiber Html tag not respecting if object is in front

Tags: html, reactjs, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I have been working with React Three Fiber for a while now. I'm implementing a `Html` tag in my code, this html tag will have a page for now. Although, all the content inside this html tag, doesn't seem to respect the objects at all, if a object is in front, i will just ignore and insert the content from the tag in front.
Like this, As you can see the chair is being cutted:

[image]

This is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Html } from "@react-three/drei";

export default function Monitor({ geometry, bakedTexture }: any) {
  return (
    <>
      <mesh geometry={geometry}>
        <meshBasicMaterial map={bakedTexture} />
      </mesh>
      <Html
        transform
        wrapperClass="htmlScreen"
        distanceFactor={1.17}
        position={[-2.57, 1.8, -0.01]}
        rotation-y={1.565}
        occlude
      >
        <iframe src="https://bruno-simon.com/html/" />
      </Html>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have a occlude property, in which "works", but not as desired, since it hides the content from the iframe. What I'm attempting to perform, is for the HTML tag to work similar to any other object, and when there is an object in front, it won't overlap, but instead will show the frame on the back of that object.

I have attempted doing the following too.

```
import { useLayoutEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useGLTF, useTexture, useMask, Mask, Html } from "@react-three/drei";

import Chair from "../Chair";
import Monitor from "../Monitor";
import StaticRoom from "../StaticRoom";

export default function Room() {
  const stencil = useMask(1, true);
  const { nodes }: any = useGLTF("./models/room/room.glb");
  const bakedTexture = useTexture("./models/room/baked.png");

  bakedTexture.flipY = false;

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    Object.values(nodes).forEach((node: any) => {
      return (
        node.material &&
        node.name !== "room" &&
        node.name !== "Scene" &&
        node.name !== "monitor" &&
        node.name !== "chair" &&
        node.name !== "screen" &&
        Object.assign(node.material, stencil)
      );
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <StaticRoom geometry={nodes.room.geometry} bakedTexture={bakedTexture} />
      <Chair geometry={nodes.chair.geometry} bakedTexture={bakedTexture} />
      <Monitor geometry={nodes.monitor.geometry} bakedTexture={bakedTexture} />
      <Mask
        id={1}
        colorWrite={false}
        depthWrite={false}
        geometry={nodes.screen.geometry}
        // position={[0, 0, 9.89]}
      >
        <Html
          transform
          wrapperClass="htmlScreen"
          distanceFactor={1.17}
          position={[-2.57, 1.8, -0.01]}
          rotation-y={1.565}
        >
          <iframe src="https://bruno-simon.com/html/" />
        </Html>
      </Mask>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Any solution to this - I am seeing the same issue... Trying to fix at source, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try `<Html occlude="blending" ... />`, it will respect objects in front, but switch to CSS renderer, so you loose a little bit of quality, in my experience.